# How to apply CSS to arrays rendered by React in v15?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In React v15 elements of arrays in JSX are now rendered as `<!--react-text:some_id-->text<!--/react-text-->` instead of spans.  I've looked but I can't seem to figure out how one would apply CSS styles to those elements. Is this possible or do I need to map the array to generate spans manually now and apply CSS to the spans?

e.g.

`this.props.items.map((item,i) => { return <span>{item}</span>})`

Comment: Are you sure adding css to spans is a good idea in the first place? why not add a classname to whatever element you want inside the map?

Comment: If you ignore the `<!-- -->` comments, it's just text, right? Just imagine there's no React, how would apply CSS to that text? By putting a class on the containing element. If that isn't possible then yes, just wrap them in spans.

Comment: That seems like a good suggestion but was also just generally curious about how or if you could apply css to the text that's now rendered in this manner. @DavidGilbertson : I tried that, doesn't work in my case.  I have a workaround in place though.

Comment: note you can more simply do `this.props.items.map(item => <span>{item}</span>)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best answer is a combination of using the map function to specifically render the items as whatever type of html element you prefer (i.e. spans, divs, etc.) and using @azium's suggestion of using a custom className for the element if so desired.

i.e.

`var customSpans = this.props.items.map(
   item => <span className='someCssClass'>{item}</span>
);`